# what does the mySQL Length parameter do for different types?

Tags: mysql, types, size

I've used MySQL (via PHPMyAdmin) a lot before but never really understood half of it. I'm assuming that for `varchar`, length is the maximum length of a string that can go there. But what about for `Int`? According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), `Int` is a 4 byte integer, so why have a Length parameter for it? Is it the number of bits for that integer? Why have seperate numeric types when you can just specify the size of `Int`? What about for other data types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numeric types, the size is neither bits nor bytes. It's just the display width, that is used when the field has ZEROFILL specified.

Source: http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/